# Method to ping a user about a question I think they know the answer to, within the site

Tags: feature-request

This may be an overall site-design question, re: all the SE sites.

I have a pal that spends more time on SO, but stops over here occasionally. I see lots of questions on DBA.se that I may not know the answer to, but I'm sure he would. Same for another pal who is an Oracle expert. It would be nice if there was some way to notify them of the question using the SE inbox as opposed to having to email or FB the question out. Is this possible?

Comment: See this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Example showing share popup]

This is the only preferred way to tell people about a new question or answer they may have expertise in, and the feature you're requesting has been asked for network wide in the past.

Here's an example question like what you're asking from our main-meta

> [What's the best way to invite a user to answer a question on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40879/whats-the-best-way-to-invite-a-user-to-answer-a-question-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 5):

For DBA.SE specifically, if it's someone that's a regular you can ping them in [The Heap](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap), our chat room, as well.

We have a number of SQL Server folks, Oracle folks, MySQL folks, and data warehousing/design experts that hang out and chat about database and non-database topics.

Comment: Chat is good, but for me it's blocked @ work unfortunately.